# Navigating between activities in android

Tags: android

Can someone tell me how do the following works:
in an application there are something like header with titles. So you can scroll the screen down to see all its information and then throw it to the left and see another screen, like with messages.
This functionality of vk.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are after is a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) and a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) used with a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). 
The ViewPager gives you the funcionality of swiping left and right, and the Fragment class is a really good way of implementing things, since they are reusable and can be placed in different activities.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)? You can see it's functionality in Play store application.

Answer (score 1):

You need use class ViewPager. My advice - use fragment.